# How to convert dataframe to a 3D ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe df like this:

```
                                                        value                  
days                                                      1          2    3     
msno                                         features                           
++orpnUqSevh2M5A97pRRiONA58g5m9DwaNrhD44HY0= num_100      0.0     77.000  0.0   
                                             num_25       0.0     78.000  0.0   
                                             num_50       0.0     13.000  0.0   
                                             num_75       0.0      3.000  0.0   
                                             num_985      0.0      3.000  0.0   
                                             num_unq      0.0     84.000  0.0   
                                             total_secs   0.0  18987.862  0.0 
+0krxpTkQT7hciN95OEp7i2lyKvbXft887VNQGF6xN4= num_100      0.0      0.000  0.0   
                                             num_25       0.0      0.000  0.0   
                                             num_50       0.0      0.000  0.0   
                                             num_75       0.0      0.000  0.0   
                                             num_985      0.0      0.000  0.0   
                                             num_unq      0.0      0.000  0.0   
                                             total_secs   0.0      0.000  0.0
```

How can I convert it to a 3D ndarray?
I have tried

```
x = np.array(list(df.groupby('msno').apply(pd.DataFrame.as_matrix)))
```

But it said :TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

3D ndarray looks like:

```
[[[ 0  0  0 ...,  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 ...,  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 ...,  0  0  0]
  ..., 
  [ 0  0  0 ...,  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 ...,  0  0  0]
  [ 0  0  0 ...,  0  0  0]]]
```

[msno,features,days]

Comment: How shuold your 3d  array  look like ?

Comment: like:[[[ 0 77.000   0 ...,  0  0  0]
  [ 0  78.000  0 ...,  0  0  0]
  [ 0  13.000  0 ...,  0  0  0]
  ...,

Comment: You mean this `[df.set_index(['msno','features']).values]` ?

Comment: No, this is 2D. I need 3D

Comment: Whats the purpose of doing it>? Will converting it to `np.array([df.set_index(['msno','features']).values])` help?

Comment: No...so sad....